# How to convert c # inline queries into stored procedure written in transact sql?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have lots of SQL queries written inline in C# using .net framework.
For Example

```
string sMysql = @"
SELECT
[Something]
from Person where person_uid=12"
```

I want it to convert it to stored procedures which will be written in transact SQL.

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[aspnet_AnyDataInTables]
    @uid int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
    [Something]
    from Person where person_uid=@uid
END
```

I can do it manually but I have lots of inline queries to convert. Is there a way to do this hectic job programmatically?

Comment: Genuine question: why do you want to make them into stored procedures? I fully understand the desire to *parameterise* the first one, but it doesn't need to be a stored procedure to do that. I just want to make sure you're doing something *for the right reasons*....

Comment: Have you considered instead moving to using LINQ-to-SQL? - It may be easier to convert the queries by hand rather than parsing strings from your source, working out how to parametrise them, creating the stored procedure, changing the code and verifying the changes...

Comment: @Marc Gravell Stored procedures are performance wise more efficient and easily maintainable and also secure.

Comment: @Rowland Shaw Thanks for recommendation but i am not decision maker of project i am currently working.

Comment: @Ashirvad no, that information is incorrect. They are not any more performant than correctly parameterised queries, and I would say that it is *less* maintainable as a stored-proc, as you get issues with deployment (where-as in the app-tier, the code is inbuilt). The security one is perhaps more valid, but frankly if that is a genuine problem when talking ASP.NET, you are already past the point where you've got a problem - you're already compromised.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, throw out the stored procedure idea, and change your code snippet to the following:

```
// initialize UID value and SQL query with parameter placeholder
int uid = 12;
sql = "SELECT [Something] FROM [Person] WHERE [person_uid] = @UID";

// initialize connection and open
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("<connection string>")
{     
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)
    // add UID parameter
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UID", uid);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();        
        // execute and read results
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // process results        
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle exceptions
    }
}
```

As stated in question comments, stored procedures aren't necessarily faster than inline parameterized queries. SQL Server will even cache execution plans for queries that aren't parameterized, but I prefer the explicit declaration of parameters.

Take a look at [this article on execution plan caching and reuse for SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055.aspx) if you want more information.

Comment: You will not find an automated process to convert all of your data access code to stored procedures that is any less labor (and time) intensive than manual conversion. The parameterized query approach is a valid alternative (i.e. "the tastier tomato") because it achieves the performance results you are looking for, and keeps your modification efforts focused in application changes (instead of application and database changes that the stored procedure approach requires).